# Having opened an Excel workbook I need to use the data within across multiple MS Access VBA functions

Tags: vba, ms-access

In MS Access I have opened an Excel workbook and now, dependent on the value in a specific cell of that workbook, I want to trigger a number of alternative functions.  How do I reference the open workbook in those multiple functions without repeating the opening of the workbook each time?  Many thanks.

```
            Set XLApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
        XLApp.UserControl = True
        
        With XLApp
            XLApp.Visible = True
            Set xlwb = XLApp.ActiveWorkbook
            Set xlws = xlwb.Worksheets("Data")
            
            With xlws
                RowCount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            End With
                           
                Do While Counter <= RowCount
                    If .Range("D" + CStr(Counter)).Value = 1 Then
                        'Process new request - Access Function 1
                    'ElseIf
                        '.Range("D" + CStr(Counter)).Value = 2 then
                        'Process amend request  - Access Function 2
                    'ElseIf
                        '.Range("D" + CStr(Counter)).Value = 3 then
                        'Process delete request  - Access Function 3
                    'Else
                        'Throw error
                    End If
                    Counter = Counter + 1
                Loop
```

Comment: Instead of defining those variables inside of a subroutine or function, define them at the top level of the form or module.

Comment: a) Standard module exposing the fields you need though public properties or b) class module where you can pass the instance around.

Comment: Superb!  That seems to have worked.  Merci Olivier :-)

Comment: Many thanks for your feedback too Kostas :-)